# Modifying lines in a file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a given file text.txt that contains chapters of a book that are numbered with roman numerals. I need to write a program that rewrites the given file to a new.txt where the numerals are replaced with regular numbers from 1 to 3. In addition, the program should ask a user for an input of a number and print out that specific chapter.

```
def main():
    found = False
    search=input('Enter a description of a chapter in Roman numerals: ')
    new_num = int(input('Enter a new number: '))

    text=open('sentence.txt', 'r')
    new_file=open('new.txt', 'w')
    descr=sentence.readline()

    while line!='':
       num=float(sentence.readline())
       descr = descr.rstrip('\n')

       if descr == search: #trying to capture the roman numeral
          new_file.write(descr + '\n')
          new_file.write(str(new_num) + '\n') #trying to substitute roman numeral with a number

          found=True
       else:
#writing the original record to the temp file with regular numbers
          new_file.write(descr + '\n')
          new_file(str(new_num) + '\n')

       descr=sentence.readline()
    sentence.close()
    new_file.close()

    if found:
           print("The file has been rewritten")
    else:
           print('Not found')
main()
```

So far I tried to substitute an input of 'I' to a regular number and write it to a new file. However, the program keeps giving me errors...

Is there a way not to ask for an input but to substitute only the Roman numerals indicating chapters of the book with regular numbers and rewrite the rest of the text to a new file? Any suggestions how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which errors you see? This line seems to be incorrect:

```
new_file(str(new_num) + '\n')
```

Maybe should be:

```
new_file.write(str(new_num) + '\n')
```